# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: sockets, heroku

I have a Meteor app hosted on Heroku and the problem is that the websocket handshake fails responding with a 400 status code.
From my understanding websockets should be supported on Heroku at this point.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Any progress on this?